# Resizing a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas; how can you resample a number of points into a smaller number sample. So making this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10000)))]
```

into say the mean values represented in 1000 points of data.

Similar to `df.resample("M").mean()` but for discrete 10 point intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 10).mean()
```

If RangeIndex:

```
df.index // 10
```